# Cant access the index file with the extension removed

Tags: nginx

i'm using the following rule on nginx in order to remove the `/index.php` and make it hust `/index` however when i'm browsing the site folder `example` its says `No input file specified.` Any way to fixit or even redirect from `/example` to `/example/index` ?

This is the code i'm using to remove the .php extension

```
  if (!-f $request_filename){
            set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "1"){
            rewrite ^/([^.]+)$ /$1.php last;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need "not" to have an extension on the file, specialy the index file.
If get your example.com/index.php and just use example.com/ it's the same thing. Your webserver knows what to display.

If you want it to parse all files with no extension as php files you need to change the nginx configuration files that run php as cgi to read all files not just .php or older .php3 as php files, and parse them properly. (it's not advised as it may result in webserver problems.. nobody does that)

Comment: and please do not try to remove the extension because it'll break any search engine crawlers..